# undo tree in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, undo

Did anyone use undo tree in spacemacs? I configured it in spacemacs

```
 (global-undo-tree-mode 1)
```

but it doens't work. how to let it work?

It shows the error message of 
"unrecognized entry in undo list undo-tree-canary"

Comment: [This GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/298) suggests that this was a known issue for a while, but the bug was fixed.  Can you pull the latest version of `undo-tree.el` from MELPA, or failing that, straight from GH, and see if it goes away?

Comment: I am using the latest spacemac 0.103, but still have such issue

Answer (score 2):

This works on the latest develop, (fresh installation). open `undo-tree-visualise` with `SPC a u`. be sure that you have the minimum emacs version:

```
(defconst spacemacs-emacs-min-version   "24.3" "Minimal version of Emacs.")
```